# DNS server can't find PTR record: NXDOMAIN

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

I tried to set up `bind` DNS in Ubuntu.

I have 2 machine:

machine A is client:

```
IP: 192.168.190.176  
hostname: example.com
```

machine B is DNS Server:

```
IP: 192.168.190.171
```

In DNS server:

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
};
//reverse zone
zone "190.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

`/etc/bind/db.example.com`:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     example.com.        root.example.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      example.com.
@       IN      A       192.168.190.176
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
```

`/etc/bind/db.192`:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     example.com. root.example.com. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      example.com.
176.190.168     IN      PTR     example.com.
```

And in Client:

```
nslookup 192.168.190.176
Server:     192.168.190.171
Address:    192.168.190.171#53

** server can't find 176.190.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Can you fix it?

UPDATE:
I try with nslookup example.com

server can't find example.com: SERVFAIL

Comment: Just use `176    IN      PTR     example.com.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overdoing it.

In your `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` file, you have already declared the snippet for reverse zone `190.168.192.in-addr.arpa` i.e. `192.168.190`:

```
zone "190.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

Now in `/etc/bind/db.192` file, you just need to refer to the last octet of the IP address, not the whole address; in fact, even more than one octet would be incorrect.

Presumably you are planning to assign `176` as the  last octet i.e. the `PTR` RR, so just add:

```
176     IN      PTR     example.com.
```

Comment: But i try test with nslookup example.com, it don't work

Comment: I found resolve way, just ping -a ip

Comment: `dig` is your friend for testing DNS